# Converting date shows 31-Dec-69

Tags: php

I want to convert date into `d-M-y` format and it seems that i am doing something wrong. Kindly help me to correct it.

```
<?php
$date = '30/04/2017';
echo date('d-M-y', strtotime($date));
?>
```

**My Output:**
`31-Dec-69`

By I want output as `30-Apr-17`

Comment: the date you have defined in $date is having slashes so first convert it into (-) then convert hope you will get

Comment: the coming format is always like dd/mm/yyy or dd-mm-yyyy  etc in short you first get dd like 01 or 15. am I right ?

Comment: @krishnpatel it can be dd/mm/yyy or dd-mm-yyyy or d/m/y or d/M/yyyy or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '30/04/2017');
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

Comment: This method assumes that format is in `d/m/Y` i dont want that.

Comment: @Abhishek you must define which format has date before converting, because f.e. 04/10/2017 can be as April as October

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime objects when you're working with dates and times. You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse the date string and then the DateTime::format() to format it the way you want:

```
<?php
$str = '30/04/2017';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $str);
echo $date->format('d-M-Y'); 
?>
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/726560)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$date = '30-04-2017';
echo date('d-M-y', strtotime($date));

?>
```

or use

```
<?php
  $date = '25/05/2010';
  $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
  echo date('d-M-y', strtotime($date));
?>
```

Comment: The slash format is coming from different source. I cant control that.

Comment: then split the date first and keep into (-) format

Comment: Yeah that seems to be a solution but i don't have control over the format in source it can be anything /,- or any other. @SoniyaReddy

Comment: you are getting the parameter as date right after getting you are storing in a variable you have to change their

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date = '30/04/2017';

$newDate = str_replace('/', '-', $date);

echo date('d-M-y', strtotime($newDate));

?>

// Output: 30-Apr-17
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7dfab60253049a6bd055009ca6dad72a98983729)